# why i am been charged for "Azure App Service" while i do not have any active ones

Tags: office-365, azure

Today i was checking the "cost analysis" for my Azure Subscription, and i found that i have 23 USD as actual cost for "Azure App Service", as follow:-

[image: User's image]

Although all the App services in my case are been stopped 3 months ago:-

[image: User's image]

so why i am been charged for something i am not using and which is stopped?